# MongoDB Count based on output on one field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongojs

Suppose I have this following dataset,

```
//listings collection

{
  "city": New York,
  "beds": 2,
  "build": concrete
}

{
  "city": New York,
  "beds": 4,
  "build": wood
}

{
  "city": New York,
  "beds": 3,
  "build": asphalt
}

{
  "city": New York,
  "beds": 1,
  "build": concrete
}
```

I can get the number of following averages of beds with the following query

```
        db.listings.aggregate(
            [  
                {  
                    $match: {  
                        "city": "New York"
                    }
                },
                {  
                    $group: {  
                        "_id": null,
                        "Avg-Beds": {  
                            $avg:"$beds
                         }
                    }
                }
            ])
```

Which is cool, but what I'm really looking for is something like

```
{
    "Avg-Beds": 2
    "Build" {
                "Asphalt" : 1,
                "Wood": 1,
                "Concrete": 2

}
```

In summary, I want to average the beds, but I want to count the output of `"build"` field at the same time.
How is this achievable with mongodb?

Even better would be something like an output of

```
"Build": {
           "Asphalt": "25%"
 }
```

Which would give a percentage based value. Note that I do not have a predefined set of `"build"` output fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below aggregation:

```
db.listings.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { "city": "New York" }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            avg: { $avg: "$beds" },
            docs: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$docs"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$docs.build",
            avg: { $first: "$avg" },
            beds: { $sum: "$docs.beds" }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            avg: { $first: "$avg" },
            total: { $sum: "$beds" },
            Build: { $push: { k: "$_id", v: "$beds" } }
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            Build: {
                $map: {
                    input: "$Build",
                    as: "b",
                    in: {
                        k: "$$b.k",
                        v: { $divide: [ "$$b.v", "$total" ] }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            avg: 1,
            Build: { $arrayToObject: "$Build" }
        }
    }
])
```

The thing is that you need multiple independent aggregations so you can perform first one (`$avg`) and then embed its result into each document of your collection (pushing all the documents under `docs` field and the unwinding that field). Then you can build an array of `k`-`v` pairs to apply [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/) to represent percentages.

As a result you'll get:

```
{ "avg" : 2.5, "Build" : { "asphalt" : 0.3, "wood" : 0.4, "concrete" : 0.3 } }
```

Comment: Would it be simpler to not calculate the percentage? but rather a simple count? I can live with calculating percentages outside of a query.

Comment: All you have to do is replace `v: { $divide: [ "$$b.v", "$total" ] }` with `v: "$$b.v"` to get counts instead of percentage

Comment: K. This rather looks somewhat complex for a simple concept. Not sure if this will be friendly to my developers. Thanks.